# JTextField and JTextArea randomly not working when program is run

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I just learning java now and I am trying to figure out what is wrong, but every time I run the code I get a different result. It is a program that I am writing more or less to figure out how to use java, but some of the objects are not appearing the way they should be.

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

 JButton button = new JButton();
 JTextField textField = new JTextField();
 JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
 int buttonClicked;

public Main() {
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); // creates toolkit
    Dimension screenSize = tk.getScreenSize(); // sets screen dimensions
    Dimension frameDim = new Dimension(400, 400); // sets frame dimensions
    int xPos = (screenSize.width / 2) - (frameDim.width / 2); // sets xPos
    int yPos = (screenSize.height / 2) - (frameDim.height / 2); // sets yPos

    this.setSize(frameDim); // sets jframe size
    this.setVisible(true); // sets jframe visible
    this.setLocation(xPos, yPos); // sets jframe location to xPos and yPos
    this.setResizable(false); // sets Resizable to false
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // exits on close
    this.setTitle("This is a Frame");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // creates a panel
    this.add(panel); //adds panel to JFrame

    JLabel label = new JLabel("I'm a label"); // creates a label with text
    label.setText("I say something"); // changes the text in the label
    label.setToolTipText("this is a label"); // sets the tool-tip
    panel.add(label); // adds the label to the panel

    JButton button = new JButton("I am a button"); // creates a button
    button.setText("I am still a button"); // changes text on the button
    button.setBorderPainted(true); // adds border (default)
    button.setContentAreaFilled(true); // adds area inside border (default)
    button.setToolTipText("It's a button"); // sets the tool-tip
    panel.add(button); // adds the button to the panel

    JTextField textField = new JTextField("words", 15); // creates textField
    textField.setColumns(10); // sets textField size
    textField.setText(""); //changes textField text
    textField.setToolTipText("this is a textField"); // sets the tool-tip
    panel.add(textField); //adds textField to the panel

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 20);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    panel.add(textArea);
    JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    panel.add(scrollBar);
    this.add(panel);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
//      new TestTextArea();
}
}
```

the problem is that when I run this is pretty much a shot in dark of whether or not the textArea and textField will appear in the window. Sometimes, but very rarely, the button and label don't even appear... I can't think of a solution.

I am running java 7 update 60 if this helps, also it did not work on update 55 either

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in every Swing tutorial, but I'll repeat it again. You shouldn't call `setVisible(true)` before all the elements are added. That should be the last thing you do, just after calling `this.pack()`.

Moreover, Swing components should never be used outside of the event disptach thread. You're doing everything in the main thread. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

And finally, the panel should be added once, and not twice, to the frame.

Comment: Ok i added the panel a second time because I thought it was making a difference and it wasn't, I just forgot to delete before I added it to this thread... And thank you for telling to set the frame to visible at the end, in the tutorial I watched he did not say that I should do that but looking back at it he did have it at the end... and I don't know what it means the event dispatch thread is... so I will look it up at the link that you posted, thank you every much

Answer (score 5):

Move the call to `setVisible(true)` to the *end* of the code.

Other tips:

1. See the advice of @trashgod.
2. Don't set the size of the frame, but instead call `pack()` after all components are added.
3. To set a GUI in the center of the screen, use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` but better is to use `setLocationByPlatform(true)` before the GUI is visible.  For frame positioning, you cannot go by `setLocationByPlatform(true)`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for demo.

[image]